# Laravel form request - $this->user() vs. auth()->user() in authorization

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

Can anyone explain if there is a reason why we should not be using getting the authenticated user within a from request `authorize` method, via the `Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()` helpers vs. the `$this->user()` method as suggested in docs?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#authorizing-form-requests

In my case, I am trying to unit test a form request and `auth()->user()` allows me to retrieve the user whereas `$this->user()` does not as I am not making a full request. I am just creating the form request object for my test.

```
public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->subject = new \App\Http\Requests\OrderStoreRequest();
}

// Acting as has no effect when manually creating the orderStoreRequest object
public function testAuthorize()
{
    $this
        ->actingAs(\factory(User::class)->create())
        ->assertTrue($this->subject->authorize());
}
```

Comment: I absolutely recommend not doing that test, you are testing the framework, not your code... what you want to test is hitting an endpoint and then assert that everything works, for example, your endpoint creates a new model of your own, test it got created. If you want to test that the user gets denied when it is not authorized or even logged in, hit the endpoint and the assert the response with `$response->assertForbidden()` or `$response->assertUnauthorized()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActingAs()` is calling the Laravel Auth system, which in the request lifecycle is put into the request ([See](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/2778eeb3b5a0eefcb28efa358c79ab3faf5f0376/AuthServiceProvider.php#L80)). Since you are just calling your request without this lifecycle, you will never get anything injected into the Request.

For your code to work, you need to set the UserResolver. This can be done like so.

```
$this->subject->setUserResolver(function () use($user) {
   return $user;
});
```

For ease of usage, i would highly recommend doing Laravel feature tests instead of unit testing. You are gonna fight your way through a lot of approaches, there is not meant to be called without the Laravel lifecycle. Which you will get doing call() and json() on the app.